# Why didn't it work when I tried to print the value of integer using character type, float type?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void integer(int *i)
{
  char *c;
  float *f;
  c=(char *)&i;
  f=(float *)&i;
  printf("value you entered in integer is: %d",*i);
  printf("value you entered in character is: %s",*c);
  printf("value you entered in float is: %f",*f);
}
int main()
{
  int x;
  printf("enter any integer:\n");
  scanf("%d",&x);
  integer(&x);
  return(0);
}
```

The was the code I tried. How can I print the integer in terms of character and float?

Comment: *How can I print the integer in terms of character and float?* what do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: This is one of the questions i got while i was taking quiz exam...

Comment: So many mistakes in such a small piece of code. First of all, you are passing `int* i` to the function, so you should remove that `&` in the two castings that follow (or pass `int i` instead). Second, printing `"...%s",*c` - What the hell are you hoping to print, a character or a string? If character, then use `%c` instead of `%s`. If string, then use `c` instead of `*c`. Please note that in the case of `%s`, it is extremely unsafe, and in general yields undefined behavior, because `c` is not necessarily pointing to a null-terminated string (within memory boundaries).

Comment: (Continuing the previous comment:) In the case of `%c`, you'll be printing the first byte of the integer value. This will be the LSB of the integer value on Little-Endian architectures, and the MSB of the integer value on Big-Endian architectures. In either case, this character will most likely appear as some arbitrary ASCII symbol, and it's most likely not going to be a decimal digit. Are you sure that's what you want to print???

Comment: With regards to the `float`, you should pray that `sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)`. Although this is indeed the case on most platforms, it is not guaranteed by the C-language standard, so this part of the code also yields undefined behavior (at least according to the standard). Even though it will most likely not cause any runtime exception, it essentially violates the [strict aliasing rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing), which you may want to read about.

Comment: It was silly mistake i have mad about %s i din't check it properly. And that's  what i wanted to print.

Comment: So read my **second** comment carefully.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to pass the address of the input. Pass it by value. Then cast it.  That is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void integer(int i) 
{
 char c;
 float f;
 c=(char)i;
 f=(float)i;
 printf("value you entered in integer is: %d\n",i);
 printf("value you entered in character is: %c\n",c);
 printf("value you entered in float is: %f\n",f);
}
int main()
{
 int x;
 printf("enter any integer:\n");
 scanf("%d",&x);
 integer(x);
 return(0); 
}
```

Comment: I tried the above program what you have given but it was stopping after the integer value printed.....By the way I need to get it by using pointers.

Comment: What do you need pointers from unless you want to violate the aliasing rule causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: i just need one example of it

Comment: If you need pointers so bad then try the code i am posting next.@PrasanthSai

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the [Strict aliasing rule](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html) eventually leading to undefined behavior.

Presuming you want to print out the the character using its ASCII value then you can do:

```
printf("%c\n",i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void integer(int *i) 
 {
  printf("value you entered in integer is: %d\n",*i);
  printf("value you entered in character is: %c\n",(char)(*i));
  printf("value you entered in float is: %f\n",(float)(*i));
  }
 int main()
   {
    int x;
    printf("enter any integer:\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    integer(&x);
    return(0); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to print different *representations* of the *same* value, or are you trying to interpret the same binary pattern as *different* values?

In simpler language, if you enter the integer value `100`, do you want to display

```
value you entered in integer is: 100
value you entered in character is: "100"
value you entered in float is: 100.000000
```

or

```
value you entered in integer is: 100
value you entered in character is: d           
value you entered in float is: 0.000000
```

In the first case, you'd use something like

```
float f = *i; // conversion happens as part of assignment, no need for cast

char c[N+2];   // where N is the number of digits (10 for 32-bit int, 20 for 
               // 64-bit)

sprintf( c, "%d", *i );

printf( "value you entered in integer is: %d\n", *i );
printf( "value you entered in chararcter is: \"%s\"\n", c );
printf( "value you entered in float is: %f\n", f );
```

In the second case, you'd do something like

```
union { int i; float f} u;
u.i = *i;

printf( "value you entered in integer is: %d\n", *i );
printf( "value you entered in chararcter is: %c", (char) *i );
printf( "value you entered in float is: %f\n", u.f );
```

You *don't* want to do

```
float *f = (float *) i;
```

or

```
float f = *(float *) i;
```

as that violates the strict aliasing rule:

> **6.5 Expressions**
> ...
> 7 An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
> the following types:<sup>88)</sup>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
> object,
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the
> effective type of the object,
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
> members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
> — a character type